# How to Update Jquery Data Table

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using Jquery data table plugin. I was able to display it properly with filtering, sorting and Paging.

But, now the problem is i need to filter the data table rows based on dropdown selection made.

but, i do not have any idea how to do this..I am very new to MVC. So, here i need to send that dropdown selected item as parameter to a server side method and call a method and rebind data to the data table.

I am initially binding data to the data table using for loop and iterating over a datatable

Do i need to use Ajax here..if so how to get the new datatable/data to this view and bind to data table?

Please suggest the way to do..

Comment: if u need to send to server, yes, you need to use ajax to do that, refer to this http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Comment: How to bind the data to grid again..do i need to destroy existing or can i replace directly with new set of rows

Comment: without any code, I had no idea what had u actually done

Answer (score 0):

you use the jquery datatable for this 
create function and paste jquery datatable code in there
then call this function on dropdown selection change using jquery.

Tips :jquery datatable code available on net find and use it